# How to translate large pdf from comand line?

Tags: command-line, pdf, translation

I have a large pdf file (83 MB) and I want to translate it. I tried to split the file with `pdftk` and translate each part with https://www.onlinedoctranslator.com/en/ (The file can't be larger than 10 MB) but it is very labor-intensive. The preferred translator would be Google engine. If there is no easy way to automatize this task It would be helpful if you give me a tip how to split pdf to parts of even size (in MBs).

Comment: 83mb is large? :-P  Have a look at `translate-shell` We use that to translate from command line and it uses googleservices. I would assume you could then just a loop and use sed to replace contents in the pdf.

Comment: Links https://www.2daygeek.com/translate-shell-a-tool-to-use-google-translate-from-command-line-in-linux/#  Project page https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell

Comment: Addendum to @Rinzwind s comment `translate-shell` is available through multiverse repository in xenial, bionic, cosmic, and disco. Link: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=translate-shell&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Comment: @dessert well the good answer should contain an example how to translate pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at translate-shell

- [Project page](https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell)
- [Website](https://www.2daygeek.com/translate-shell-a-tool-to-use-google-translate-from-command-line-in-linux/#)

This installs a command called `trans` where you can tell it to translate. Examples from the project page.

> Translate Shell (formerly Google Translate CLI) is a command-line translator powered by Google Translate (default), Bing Translator, Yandex.Translate, and Apertium. It gives you easy access to one of these translation engines in your terminal:

```
$ trans 'Saluton, Mondo!'
Saluton, Mondo!

Hello, World!

Translations of Saluton, Mondo!
[ Esperanto -> English ]
Saluton ,
    Hello,
Mondo !
    World!
```

> By default, translations with detailed explanations are shown. You can also translate the text briefly: (only the most relevant translation will be shown)

```
$ trans -brief 'Saluton, Mondo!'
Hello, World!
```

You can also tell it to use a language:

```
trans :fr word
```

And there is even more:

```
trans -browser firefox :fr http://www.w3.org/
```

will open firefox with a French translation of www.w3.org.

There is no method for directly translating a PDF. Method for a file:

```
trans :fr file://input.txt
```

Now in relation to a PDF:

```
sudo apt install poppler-utils
```

with that tool you can make a text file from the pdf.

```
pdftotext your.pdf your.txt
```

- add `-layout` to preserve layout
- add `-opw {password}` if there is a password

and you can feed the file

```
trans file://your.txt
```

Next step: back to PDF

```
sudo apt-get install enscript ghostscript
```

and convert to postscript and then to pdf:

```
enscript -p output.ps your.txt
ps2pdf output.ps your2.pdf
```

I got this working on a PDF with some words in it. No guarantee it works on a large file so please comment below if this worked.

Comment: Well, for large files it prints an unformatted version. Also you forgot to mention encodings: `cat <your.txt> | iconv -f latin1 -t iso-8859-1 | enscript -X 88591 -o - | ps2pdf - output.pdf`